# Token management source code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, authorization

I have four servers and one API request to get AuthToken. Practically I feel like storing the token in DB, so it's shared across four servers. However I know that some store it in txt files, or memcache, etc.

Could you tell me if there are any good practices (with source code) to follow? How can I manage and share one AuthToken across multiple production servers? How and when should I expire it? And anything that a dev should know about AutToken management.